# Text overlay on image hover wont work on my grid

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to have text appear instead of image on hover in my grid. I tried using the w3schools example but it did not work with my code at all. Here is my code. Also any tips or comments on my code is appreciated.

My code does not have any hover attempts in it, I deleted all my attempts and this is where it was before.

HTML

```
<!-- Header Logo -->
    <div class="hlogo">
        <a href="Home">Hidden Listen</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Header Links -->

     <div class="navbar">
        <a href="Home">Home</a>
        <a href="Reviews">Reviews</a>
        <a href="Artists">Artists</a>
     </div>

    <!-- Grid of Home page -->

    <div class="featured">
        <div class="fmain">
            <img src="/img/Album Covers/marvel1.jpg" alt="Album Cover">
            <h1>Text hover shit</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="main1">
            <img src="/img/Album Covers/fantasy.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="main2">
            <img src="/img/Album Covers/No Dope on Sundays.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="main3">
            <img src="/img/Album Covers/Scum Tyler.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="main4">
            <img src="/img/Album Covers/syre.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
  /*Navigation Bar*/
.hlogo {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.hlogo a {
    color: #092140;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
    color: #092140;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 10px; 
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    color:#F24738;
}

/* Grid */

.featured {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
}

.featured > div {
  text-align: center;
}

.fmain {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
    position: relative;
}

.fmain img {
    width: 100%;
}

.main1 {
    grid-column: 3 / span 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.main1 img {
    width: 100%;
}

.main2 {
    grid-column: 4 / span 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.main2 img {
    width: 100%;
}

.main3 {
    grid-column: 3 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2;
}

.main3 img {
    width: 100%;
}

.main4 {
    grid-column: 4 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2;
}

.main4 img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question. Looks confusing " text appear instead of image on hover in my grid". But as u mentioned, you tried with w3school, somehow I understood you are looking for the below solution. Here, you need to add a class of your hover text and need to add the properties. Try like this below, and let me know if this is what you want or you are looking for something else.

```css
 /*Navigation Bar*/
.hlogo {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.hlogo a {
    color: #092140;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
    color: #092140;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 10px; 
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    color:#F24738;
}

/* Grid */

.featured {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
}

.featured > div {
  text-align: center;
}

.fmain {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
    position: relative;
}

.fmain img {
    width: 100%;
}

.main1 {
    grid-column: 3 / span 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.main1 img {
    width: 100%;
}

.main2 {
    grid-column: 4 / span 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.main2 img {
    width: 100%;
}

.main3 {
    grid-column: 3 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2;
}

.main3 img {
    width: 100%;
}

.main4 {
    grid-column: 4 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2;
}

.main4 img {
    width: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height:0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.fmain:hover .overlay {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header Logo -->
    <div class="hlogo">
        <a href="Home">Hidden Listen</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Header Links -->

     <div class="navbar">
        <a href="Home">Home</a>
        <a href="Reviews">Reviews</a>
        <a href="Artists">Artists</a>
     </div>

    <!-- Grid of Home page -->

    <div class="featured">
        <div class="fmain">
            <img src="/img/Album Covers/marvel1.jpg" alt="Album Cover">
            <div class="overlay">
            <h1 class="text">Text hover shit</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main1">
            <img src="/img/Album Covers/fantasy.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="main2">
            <img src="/img/Album Covers/No Dope on Sundays.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="main3">
            <img src="/img/Album Covers/Scum Tyler.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="main4">
            <img src="/img/Album Covers/syre.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to do hover using css there's many ways to do it

You have to set up the display of the text none then using `:hover` on the id of element or class will be like this `.hoverText:hover` then put the `display:block;` that's all.

https://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/n2w38whv/

```css
.hlogo {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.hlogo a {
    color: #092140;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
    color: #092140;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 10px; 
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    color:#F24738;
}

/* Grid */

.featured {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
}

.featured > div {
  text-align: center;
}

.fmain {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
    position: relative;
}
.hoverText{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    font-size: 28px;
    left: 15%;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0,3s ease;
}
.hoverText:hover{
  display: block;
}



.fmain img {
    width: 100%;
}
.fmain img:hover   ~ .hoverText {
    display:block;
}


.main1 {
    grid-column: 3 / span 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.main1 img {
    width: 100%;
}
.main2 {
    grid-column: 4 / span 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.main2 img {
    width: 100%;
}

.main3 {
    grid-column: 3 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2;
}

.main3 img {
    width: 100%;
}

.main4 {
    grid-column: 4 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2;
}

.main4 img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header Logo -->
    <div class="hlogo">
        <a href="Home">Hidden Listen</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Header Links -->

     <div class="navbar">
        <a href="Home">Home</a>
        <a href="Reviews">Reviews</a>
        <a href="Artists">Artists</a>
     </div>

    <!-- Grid of Home page -->

    <div class="featured">
        <div class="fmain">
            <img src="http://cdn.pcwallart.com/images/universe-wallpaper-3d-wallpaper-2.jpg" alt="Album Cover">
            <h1 class="hoverText">Text hover shit</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="main1">
            <img src="/img/Album Covers/fantasy.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="main2">
            <img src="/img/Album Covers/No Dope on Sundays.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="main3">
            <img src="/img/Album Covers/Scum Tyler.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="main4">
            <img src="/img/Album Covers/syre.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  .hlogo {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.hlogo a {
    color: #092140;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
    color: #092140;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 10px; 
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    color:#F24738;
}

/* GRID---- */

.grid{
      width:100%;
      position:relative;
      overflow:hidden;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin-left:120px;
}


.griditem .gridhover{
      transform: scaleY(1);
 }

.griditem{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.gridhover{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 2;
    opacity:0;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition:all 0.3s ease-in;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in;
    background: grey;
    

}
.gridhover:hover{
    opacity: 0.96;

}
.gridhover h{
    font-size:30px;
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    font-weight:700;
    line-height: 50px;

}
.gridhover p{
    font-size:20px;
    position:absolute;

}
.grid img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Header Logo -->
    <div class="hlogo">
        <a href="Home">Hidden Listen</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Header Links -->

     <div class="navbar">
        <a href="Home">Home</a>
        <a href="Reviews">Reviews</a>
        <a href="Artists">Artists</a>
     </div>
 <ul class="grid">
            
            <li class="griditem">
            <img src="https://helloworld.co.nz/images/helloworld-logo.jpg" alt="Album Cover">
              <a class="link" href="https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hello&oq=hello&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.703j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8">
                <div class="gridhover" id="marvel1">
                   <h1>Text hover shit</h1>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
            
            
            
             <li class="griditem">
            <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/9c/b7/ea/9cb7ea4872cf0622377402694c26228a.jpg" alt="Album Cover">
              <a class="link" href="https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hello&oq=hello&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.703j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8">
                <div class="gridhover" id="marvel1">
                   <h1>Text hover shit</h1>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

First off I would use a list for the grid just because it would make writing the CSS a lot easier as you could use the same CSS for all of the grid items.

If the grid images differ in size you could add a unique Id tag onto each grid item to make slight size modifications:

```
   <li class="griditem" id="special_item">
```

This format would save you time and is easier to handle
HTML format:

```
      <ul class="grid">

        <li class="griditem">
        <img src="/img/Album Covers/marvel1.jpg" alt="Album Cover">
          <a class="link" href="projects/something/something.php">
            <div class="gridhover" id="marvel1">
               <h1>Text hover shit</h1>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
```

Its a lot easier to scale this way and even if that was not the case you want to be semantically correct.

Using a list over a div in this scenario would help Google Robot, Screen Readers as well as the blind users of the internet.